# How to draw rounded corner rectangle in React Native ART

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, d3.js, svg

I'm using `react-native` `ART` library to draw scalable vector elements in my mobile app, `ART` is the perfect library due to it can be animated and morph easily with its own tools. But `ART` don't have custom elements like SVG's `Circle`, `Rect` etch..., ART have only one type called `Shape` and is powerful enough to create almost any shapes. But I'm having difficulties with drawing a scalable rounded cornered rectangle with `Shape`.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {ART} from 'react-native'

const {Group, Shape} = ART

export default class Graphics extends React.Component{
   render(){
      const {x, y, width, height, fill, stroke} = this.props;
      const d = `M0,0L${width},0L${width},${height}L0,${height}L0,0z`
      return(
        <Group x={x} y={y}>
           <Path d={d} fill={fill} stroke={stroke}>
        </Group>
      )
   }
}
```

as you can see I create rectangle shape with given width and height but I don't have any idea how to generate rounded corners.

I dont know about d3 is it possible to do this with either d3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ART` `Path` object to create paths along with paths `curve` or `curveTo` methods or `arc` `arcTo` methods. Please check the example `Rect` component below.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {ART} from 'react-native'
const {Group, Shape, Path} = ART

function Rect({fill, stroke, x, width, y, rc, height, topLeftRadius, topRightRadius, bottomRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius, ...rest}){
    const startX = 0;
    const startY = 0;
    const smallDimension = width > height ? height : width;
    let tlr = topLeftRadius !== null ? topLeftRadius : rc; tlr =  tlr > smallDimension/2 ? smallDimension /2 : tlr;
    let trr = topRightRadius !== null ? topRightRadius : rc; trr = trr > smallDimension/2 ? smallDimension /2 : trr;
    let brr = bottomRightRadius !== null ? bottomRightRadius : rc; brr = brr > smallDimension/2 ? smallDimension /2 : brr;
    let blr = bottomLeftRadius !== null ? bottomLeftRadius : rc; blr = blr > smallDimension/2 ? smallDimension /2 : blr;
    const d = Path()
                .move(startX, startY)
                .move(startX, tlr)
                .arc( tlr, startY-tlr, tlr, tlr, false, false) // top left
                .lineTo(width - trr, startY)
                .arc( trr, startX+trr, trr, trr, false, false) // top right
                .lineTo(width, startY+ (height - brr))
                .arc(startX-brr, brr, brr, brr, false, false) // bottom right
                .lineTo(startX + blr, height)
                .arc(startX-blr, startY-blr, blr, blr, false, false) // bottom right
                .close()

    return(
        <Group x={x} y={y}>
            <Shape {...rest} fill={fill} stroke={stroke} d={d}/>
        </Group>
    )
}

Rect.propTypes = {
    width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    x: PropTypes.number,
    y: PropTypes.number,
    fill: PropTypes.string,
    stroke: PropTypes.string,
    topLeftRadius: PropTypes.number,
    topRightRadius: PropTypes.number,
    bottomRightRadius: PropTypes.number,
    bottomLeftRadius: PropTypes.number,
    rc: PropTypes.number
}

Rect.defaultProps = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    fill: 'transparent',
    stroke: 'red',
    topLeftRadius: null,
    topRightRadius: null,
    bottomRightRadius: null,
    bottomLeftRadius: null,
    rc: 0
}

export default Rect
```

Here you have completely scalable independent rounded-corner support rectangle component.

- Props `width` & `height` - will normal rect no rounded corner at all.
- Props `width`, `height` & `rc` - will give you equal rounded of all corner.
- Props `width`, `height` & `topRightRadius` (or any other corner) - will give you each given rouned corner.

Please check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kamaal-/2e9be46f703612e0420b883d89ad0fba) for complete usage.[image]